# R for loop to read in xlsx files from dataframe parameters

Tags: r, for-loop, xlsx

Within R I am setting up a template of sorts that i plan to re-use and I am defining how many xlsx files I intend to import, their names and the pertinent worksheet. This is to reduce work next time around. I was hoping to use this info to also load each into it's own respective dataframe. But I can't get it working.

```
##Set up the workbooks and worksheets you'll be working with
numFiles = 2 #num
files <- data.frame(
  fileNum = c (1:numFiles),
  fileName = c("one.xlsx","two.xlsx"), #list their names
  sheetName = c("sheet1","sheet1") #list the worksheet for respective files
)

##Read workbooks
for (n in numFiles)
{
  nameTemp = paste("Data", files[[n,"fileName"]], sep = "") 
  #alternative I tried this but it didn't work:
  #assign(paste(("Data", files[[n,"fileName"]], sep = "")) = read.xlsx(files[[n,"fileName"]], sheet = files[[n,"sheetName"]])
  nameTemp = read.xlsx(files[[n,"fileName"]], sheet = files[[n,"sheetName"]])
}
```

Problem occurs during the for loop read.

I also tried using assign instead of my nameTemp, within the for loop, but I couldn't get that working either.

Comment: Try `list.files()`

Comment: I don't understand what the actual problem is. Are the files not loading? Perhaps you need `assign(nameTemp, read.xlsx(files[[n,"fileName"]], sheet = files[[n,"sheetName"]]))` for the last line?

Comment: Axeman - I tried assign but getting error "Error in file(description = xlsxFile) : invalid 'description' argument"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want, storing dataframes in a list. If you'd rather have separate objects, look into multiple assignment with `zeallot` (EDIT: added example)

```
numFiles = 2 

files <- data.frame(
  fileNum = c (1:numFiles),
  fileName = c("one.xlsx", "two.xlsx"), # try list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx") to automate this
  sheetName = c("Sheet1","Sheet2"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

data = list()

for (n in 1:numFiles) {
  data[[n]] = readxl::read_xlsx(path = files$fileName[n], sheet = files$sheetName[n])
}

library(zeallot)
c(myname1,myname2) %<-% data
```

Edit: a more concise way came to my mind, that should be closer to what you were trying to achieve:

```
numFiles = 2

files <- data.frame(
  fileNum = c (1:numFiles),
  fileName = c("one.xlsx", "two.xlsx"), # try list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx") to automate this
  sheetName = c("Sheet1","Sheet2"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

for (n in 1:numFiles) {
    assign(paste0("Data",substr(files$fileName[n],1,nchar(files$fileName[n])-5)),    # object name
           readxl::read_xlsx(path = files$fileName[n], sheet = files$sheetName[n]))  # data
}
```

Comment: Levasco - great approach. That worked for creation of "dataOne" but for some reason didn't loop through to create and fill "dataTwo" -- thoughts on why?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the error message. `data` should be a list containing several dataframes you can access with `data[[1]]`, `data[[2]]`

Comment: Oh, oh. I was mistaken by some old data in my environment (I was looking for dataOne and dataTwo or similar). Thanks - it worked!

Comment: glad it helped! added an example on how to 'unpack' a list with `zeallot`

Comment: Very neat. I'll begin to work with that. Many thanks!

Comment: Definitely nice touch at the end there. I had tried to figure that out with no luck and gave up. Definitely speeds up the loading process for those data sets. Thanks again and some more!